# Login to ASP.NET Core app using Discord's in-app OAuth Authorization & redirect

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, oauth, discord

As Discord rolled out (now for quite some time) the possibility to login to an application using OAuth from within the desktop/mobile apps themselves, without resorting to browsers (which is a pain for mobile users...), I was wondering if this was possible to pull off in ASP.NET Core.

Take this generic Discord OAuth URL, that you'd encounter inside the Discord app : https://discord.com/api/oauth2/authorize?client_id=803761073412898878&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A5001%2Fsignin-oauth2&response_type=code&scope=identify

So far, using this works flawless from within Discord, as it prompts the user for Auth, and redirects to the URI set prior within the link once you hit **Authorise** :

[image: Discord in-app OAuth flow]

Sadly, this will result, once it hits the ASP.NET app, in a 500 error on the callback when using the **AspNet.Security.OAuth.Discord** package. The reason being, there is no OAuth `state` attached to the link. Therefore, the library throws an exception outright, given the security implications.

[image: Error thrown by application]

My question then comes: Is it possible to somehow pull of this kind of authentication from within the Discord client, unattended by the ASP.NET app? Can state be bypassed from within the client, provided CSRF attack mittigation isn't compromised?

I'm open to suggestions, both on the feasability, workarounds, and possible architecture of such a solution, as this can better help Discord-to-App authentication and interactions.

Comment: Did you tried adding middleware? Could you please have a look on  this [implementations](https://github.com/Auralytical/Discord.OAuth2/blob/master/src/Discord.OAuth2/DiscordDefaults.cs). Additionally please check this [sample](https://www.yogihosting.com/discord-api-asp-net/) if that works for you

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron The git repo you sent me turned out to actually be the older implementation of the AspNet.Security.OAuth.Discord package I'm currently using. Luckily it works like a charm, until I try to go stateless, where the problem lies.
As for the sample, sadly it doesn't mitigate the issue of `state` QueryParam being empty when I try to login from within the Discord app... So I'm still at square one x')

Comment: `"Can state be bypassed from within the client"` I think it cannot be achieved, authentication will be failled in this case.